# phonegap, cordova can't add platform android

Tags: android, cordova, addition, platform

I installed both **phonegap** and **cordova**.

I created my project set my paths to tools. Now I enter my project through '**cmd**' I type:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Imagining that it will work but I get the below error:

```
Creating android project...
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone <C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit <events.js:95:17>
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit <child_process.js:795:12>
```

what could be the reason for this? what am I doing wrong? My thanks in advance.

my PATH

```
D:\Development\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
D:\Development\Android\android-sdk\tools;
D:\Development\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Java;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: have you installed android sdk with api19 and ant and added android and ant to the path and set JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME env vars?

Comment: Add `C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\npm\` to your PATH as well.

Comment: @QuickFix I did all of that sadly

Comment: @MBillau I just did what you said too but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you echo your PATH so we can see what's all on it?

Comment: @MBillau just updated my question, please check it

Comment: try to run `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` if you're on windows or `$home/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/check_reqs` if you're  on linux/osx (replace 3.3.0 with 3.4.0 if you're using cordova 3.4) and tell us what it displays

Comment: @QuickFix it says [Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.]
but I have the ant directory? as:
ANT_HOME - C:\ant\bin

Comment: ANT_HOME should point to the ant dir, not the ant\bin I think.But then later in the PATH you should have an entry like `;%ANT_HOME%/bin`. At least, that's what I have.

Comment: @MBillau ookay, did that too, still not working though

Comment: Are you sure you closed your command window and opened a new one after you changed your path with %ANT_HOME%/bin?

Comment: oh my god, I wrote it like %ANT_HOME%\bin although it should have been %ANT_HOME%/bin... thank you everyone! it works now! love you

Comment: BTW are you using Cordova 3.4? It should have printed out that ANT wasn't found and saved us some headache...

Comment: @MBillau I agree, I installed the cordova using node.js and command prompt so it should be the newest version right?

Comment: Yeah, it should be...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to create a project name without space and root folder, sub folder should not have space.

c:users\youruser>cordova create testapp com.test.testapp tesapp

This will fix your issue.